# Canonical Method to get Long Filename from User

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing a Python module which will read and analyze an input file for a specialized software program. I want the user to be able to analyze whichever input file they choose. So far I've tried 2 methods to get the file name:

**Method 1:**

```
filename = input('File to be analyzed: ')
```

Pro: simplest method

Con: difficult for user to type long file path every time

**Method 2:**

Put a file called `path.txt` in the same directory as the Python module and the user can store the filename there.

```
    import os

    pathtxt_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    pathtxt_fullpath = os.path.join(pathtxt_dir, 'path.txt')
    try:
        fo = open(pathtxt_fullpath, 'r')
        lines = fo.readlines()
        fo.close()
    except IOError:
        raise Exception('path.txt cannot be opened')
    filename = lines[0].rstrip().lstrip()  # input file
```

Pro: Coworkers are familiar with this approach since it is similar to previous programs they have used.

Con: It seems like an unnecessarily complicated way to get user input

**Question:**

Is there a canonical Python method for getting long and repetitive user inputs, like this filename? Also, is there another useful method that I have not considered?

Comment: If the users are familiar with command line inputs, just take it there via `sys.argv` or e.g. `argparse` - then their shell can autocomplete files and paths for them: `python script.py ./dir<tab>/fil<tab>`.

Comment: I don't think there's a "canonical Python method" for taking input. Python supports the same methods other languages support. It's up to you to decide which is best for your particular purpose.

Comment: Now what if they want to store the name of the input file in a file named differently than `path.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tkinter to open a GUI for them to select the file. That way they don't have to type it out every time.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
import os


def getfile(title='Choose files', sformat='.*'):
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.lift()  

    # d and f are whatever default directory and filename        

    try:
        f = fd.askopenfilename(parent=root, title=title, filetypes=[('', sformat)], initialdir=d, initialfile=f)
        root.withdraw()
        return f
    except:
        # print(title + ': error - no file exists')
        return ''
```